# PowerMock not stubbing the right method

Tags: junit4, powermock

I am facing an weird PowerMock issue. Let me explain more in details.

My code:

```
@Service 
public class TestMe {

  @Autowired
  private ClassA  a;

  @Autowired
  private ClassB  b;

  @Autowired
  private ClassStatic  staticClass;

  public void init(){
       List<String> nameList = returnNames(); // Line#1
       // Work with names 

       List<String> placeList = returnPlaces(); // Line#2
       // Work with places 
  }


  public List<String> returnNames(){
      // Code to return list of names
  }

  public List<String> returnPlaces(){
      // Code to return list of places
  }

}
```

My Test Class

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest({ClassStatic.class})
 public class TestMeTest {

 @Mock
 private ClassA  aMock;

 @Mock
 private ClassB  bMock;

 @InjectMocks
 private TestMe testMeMock;

 @Test
 public void testInit(){
     List<String> listNames = ... // some list of names 
     List<String> listPlaces = ... // some list of places

     when(testMeMock.returnNames()).thenReturn(listNames);

    // listPlaces gets returned in Line#1 shown in the main code.
     when(testMeMock.returnPlaces()).thenReturn(listPlaces); 
     testMeMock.init();
 }

}
```

So, as you see in line#1 I get listPlaces instead of listNames. If I rearrange the when calls then I get listNames instead of listPlaces at Line#2.

Why PowerMock confuses with the methods? Or there is something else I am missing while working with PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by using thenReturn twice like below

```
when(testMeMock.returnNames()).thenReturn(listNames).thenReturn(listPlaces); 

// Removed the returnPlaces() call 
// when(testMeMock.returnPlaces()).thenReturn(listPlaces); 
 testMeMock.init();
```

But why can't PowerMock distinguish between two different method calls returnNames() and returnPlaces()??

Answer (score 0):

A different perspective. This here:

```
@InjectMocks
private TestMe testMeMock;
```

and that:

```
when(testMeMock.returnPlaces()).thenReturn(listPlaces);
```

simply doesn't make sense together.

The @InjectMocks annotation is meant to create an instance of your **class under test**, which gets "filled" with the other mocks you created via the @Mock annotation. But then you use that **class under test** instance like it were a mock (by going `when(testMeMock.foo())`).

You should start by stepping back and clarifying for yourself what exactly you intend to do. Probably partial mocking, because you want to test your `init()` method, but you also intend to control what other methods on your class under test do.

Finally, you might also want to step back and re-think your overall design. To have public methods returning lists, that are also used on a public method that does the init, that simply sounds wrong, too.

Comment: Thanks for giving a different perspective. I shall look into this. So you are saying, inject mock classes shouldn't use when?